# How to create a hyperlink with parameters using DOM in PHP?

Tags: php, dom, hyperlink, parameters

I am trying to create a hyperlink using DOM in this way:

```
        //create a hyper link
        $hyperlink = $dom->createElement('a',$info[0][id]);
        $url = $dom->createAttribute('href');
        $url->value="http:/mydomain.com/index.php?type=users&user_id=1";
        $hyperlink->appendChild($url);
```

But the hyperlink doesn't work. 
When I remove the parameters

> ?type=users&user_id=1

then it works fine.

How should I pass those parameters to the hyperlink properly?

Comment: I think you need to take a look at CDATASection, http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php

Comment: the hyperlink doesn't work means what error are you getting ?

Comment: I get no error but when I view the source code in the browser no link is added when i add the ?type=users&user_id=1

Comment: @KushtrimAbdiu Thats great! :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue using @Perry's suggestion by adding the parameters to the url using CDATASection

```
$param = $dom->createCDATASection('?type=users&user_id=1');
$url->appendChild($param);
```

Comment: If this works for you. please accept your own answer